# Using a fixed point theorem.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Let $x,y \in[0,1] $, consider the following system of equations:

$$ ((x+y)/2)^n-x=0 $$ 
$$ {x^n \over x^n+y^n+1}-y=0 $$

where $ n \in N $

a) Transform the system of equations into equivalent fixed point problem.
b) Show that a solution exists by using fixed point theorem.

So my idea was to use $ y=2x^{1/n}-x $
and get
$$ f(x)  = {{x^n} \over {x^n+(2x^{1/n}-x)^n+1}}-2x^{1/n}+x=0 $$
Then the fix point of $f(x)+x $ will give a solution to the system of equations.

My question is then: 
Is this the way to proceed? or there is a better way?

Comment: If someone looks at it, I believe it is possible just to use a two original functions and have $f: R^2 \to R^2$ so $f(x,y)=(x,y)$, hence the problem is then just to prove that the domain is compact and the functions are continuous, which is fairly easy